# How to pull from IObservable

Tags: c#, observable, task-parallel-library, system.reactive, reactive

Suppose there is a `Subject<T>` at endpoint **A** and an `IObservable<T>` on endpoint **B**.

Endpoint **A** sends exactly one object of *T* using OnNext() and never calls OnComplete(). I don't have a control over that, it's in an external assembly. When I subscribe on endpoint **B** in my one, I don't get my lambda called:

```cs
endpoint.Subscribe(t => { doSomething(); });
```

However, when I subscribe like this:

```cs
using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
await endpoint.ForEachAsync(t => { doSomething(); /* cts.Cancel(); */ }, cts.Token);
```

I *do* get my lambda called. But there's a drawback. Since the publisher never calls OnCompleted(), I can't escape that async task unless I call `cts.Cancel()` after doSomething() method. It kinda works, but I don't like the idea of throwing exceptions as a part of a flow. Is there a better way?

Comment: What parts of that code do you have control over? Just the client (`A`) ? Or also `B` and all other possible subscribers? ( => Is it possible for you to make a breaking change in `B` ?)

Comment: I control only **B**. That **A** is within external library.

Comment: @SergeMisnik Can't you disassemble `A.dll`, fix the bug yourself, then rebuild it as a private dependency?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I mixed them up but that answers my question. Maybe edit that info into the question.

Comment: Is the library open source that you could suggest a bugfix to? Doesn't fix the problem short-term, though. But you could entertain a fork until it is fixed.

Comment: @Fildor Well, technically I could rebuild **A** and add OnCompleted(), but I'm not sure if that won't alter original behavior.

Comment: Is endpoint in the code A or B? What’s the relationship between A and B?

Comment: @Shlomo **B** is my client code, where I receive some data, and **A** is a client library that sort of connects somewhere and passes data to me. So, that *endpoint* is exposed in **A**.

Comment: @SergeMisnik It is still not clear how `A` is related to `B`. You are talking about how `A` generate a value but you are only working with the endpoint of `B` anyway. Why mentioning `A` at all? The `Subscribe()` callback is only called, when there is a signal produced in `B`. It is unclear what the problem is or what you are trying to do. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] (including the namespaces you are using) which shows the problem you have.

Comment: @Progman Initially, the `t => { doSomething(); }` lambda was not ever called. This brought me to blame the code in **A**. I've provided a workaround and asked if there's a better alternative for *that* workaround. Then later, all of sudden that initial *lambda* in Subscribe method started receiving signals. I've posted my solution. It's pretty much the same for both code blocks in the question. I'm not fluent in SO customs: if I keep changing the question to match the answer, what do I do with irrelevant comments that ask what is **A** or **B**? Or should I remove the question at all?

Comment: Does `endpoint.Take(1).Subscribe(t => { doSomething(); });` help? That automatically creates an `OnComplete` after the first element.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, your description is a bit confusing. If your `endpoint` sends a value without completing then you subscription should still fire fine. It just won't end without the completion or disposing of the subscription.

That can be easily fixed. Just add a `.Take(1)`.

```
endpoint.Take(1).Subscribe(t => { doSomething(); });
```

It will complete automatically after the first value.

If, instead there is a delay in the value arriving and you want to put a timeout then you have two options.

(1) You can add the `.Timeout(timeout)` operator (if `timeout` is a `TimeSpan`).

```
endpoint
    .Timeout(timeout)
    .Subscribe(
        t => { doSomething(); },
        ex => { /* timeout here */ });
```

(2) You can use the `.Amb` operator - which produces a value based on which of the two input observables fires first - to produce a default value after the length of time if a real value doesn't come.

```
endpoint
    .Take(1)
    .Amb(Observable.Timer(timeout).Select(_ => -1))
    .Subscribe(t => { doSomething(); });
```

Here you get `t == -1` if it times out - assuming that endpoint is producing an integer.

All of these options cancel when the subscription is disposed - so no need to muck around the cancellation tokens.

Comment: Appreciate for your answer! Both options look great and intuitive, similar calls actually work in my other app parts. I think there's a problem right in this async block, something to do with the actual `async/await` and the contexts. The method that calls `Subscribe` runs further and finishes before I get any messages, whichever variant I've tried and anyone suggested. For now only that weird code from my own answer holds there for a while and does receive a message in a bit. To be fair, I've added additional `Take(1)` just to be sure I get only one message.

Comment: @SergeMisnik - You know you can `await` observables too? Then you're `async` method can return the results of the observable.

Comment: Shame on me, I didn't see that `GetAwaiter` and had no idea it's *that* easy... Now it does return the result! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, one of *complicated* solutions could be:

```cs
using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
cts.CancelAfter(timeout);  // Some timeout
var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeout, cts.Token);
var stopperTask = new TaskCompletionSource();
var subscription = endpoint
                   .ObserveOn(CurrentThreadScheduler.Instance)
                   .Subscribe(t => {
                      // doSomething();
                      stopperTask.SetResult();
                   });
await Task.WhenAny(stopperTask.Task, timeoutTask);
subscription.Dispose();
if (!stopperTask.Task.IsCompleted) stopperTask.SetResult();
if (!timeoutTask.IsCompleted) cts.Cancel();
```

And thanks to @Enigmativity for a hint, it can be ***that*** simple:

```cs
// For whatever T
await endpoint.Amb(Observable.Timer(timeout).Select(_ => default(T))).Take(1);
```

Comment: You could also experiment with passing the argument `TaskCreationOptions.​RunContinuationsAsynchronously` to the `TaskCompletionSource` constructor.